# Simplify my code for Searching and Replacing Strings in an Array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I'm would like to get some help wrapping my head around simplifying this code. This works but I'm thinking there Must be a simpler way.

Goal:

1. Replace all VirtualRide w/ Ride
2. If Both VirtualRide and Ride exists in array, remove VirtualRide

eg:

```
input = ["Ride", "VirtualRide", "Run", "VirtualRun"]  expected output = ["Ride", "Run"]
input = ["VirtualRide", "VirtualRun"]                 expected output = ["Ride", "Run"]
input = ["Ride", "Run"]                               expected output = ["Ride", "Run"] (Basically do nothing)
```

This is the current code that works, but is just seems ugly and long.

```
let sportsArray = ["Ride", "VirtualRide"]
var newSportsArray = sportsArray // sportsArray is passed in. So it's a Let

 let ixVirtualRide = sportsArray.firstIndex(of: "VirtualRide")
if let ixVirtualRide = ixVirtualRide {
  
  if newSportsArray.filter({$0.contains("Ride")}).count > 1 {
    newSportsArray.remove(at: ixVirtualRide)
  }
  
  
  if newSportsArray.filter({$0.contains("VirtualRide")}).count == 1 {
    newSportsArray.remove(at: ixVirtualRide)
    newSportsArray.append("Ride")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specifications are incomplete and don't match your examples. I guess you want to

1. remove the prefix `Virtual`
2. remove duplicates (e.g. drop the `Ride` from `VirtualRide` if there is another `Ride`)
3. preserve alphabetic order (avoid `["Ride", "Run"]`)

Below code will still work when you introduce `VirtualLift`:

```
let newSportsArray = Set( // 2. remove duplicates
    sportsArray.map {
        $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "Virtual", with: "") // 1. remove prefix
    })
    .sorted() // 3. prevent arbitrary order in Set and convert to Array
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to remove any Virtual occurrence, delete the substring if matched:

```
sportsArray = sportsArray.map{$0.contains("Virtual") ? $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "Virtual", with: "") : $0}
```

Then, if the array cannot contain anything else than those four elements, use a set to clear duplicates:

```
let unique = Array(Set(sportsArray))
```

Comment: This is great. However I just noticed that each run will actually shuffle the array. Not that it matters (in this context, for my current needs) but just something that I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Here we import OrderedCollections from the Swift package library because we want to use an Ordered set to remove duplicates but maintain order:

```
import OrderedCollections
```

If Virtual isn't always at the start, and never appears anywhere else, you can use replacingOccurrences(of:) otherwise a handy extension on String helps here:

```
extension String {
    func deletingPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> String {
        guard hasPrefix(prefix) else { return self }
        return String(dropFirst(prefix.count))
    }
}
```

Now we can make a function that takes the array of strings and removes the prefixes and deduplicates the results, maintaining the order of them.

```
func f(_ s: [String]) -> [String] {
    Array(OrderedSet(s.map { $0.deletingPrefix("Virtual") }))
}
```

Then

```
f(["Ride", "VirtualRide", "Run", "VirtualRun"] // = ["Ride", "Run"]
```

etc for all your example inputs.

If you prefer this style you can write it like this too:

```
func makePrefixDeleter(_ p: String) -> (String) -> String {
    return { str in
        str.deletingPrefix(p)
    }
}

let deleteVirtualPrefix = makePrefixDeleter("Virtual")

func f(_ s: [String]) -> [String] {
    Array(OrderedSet(s.map(deleteVirtualPrefix)))
}
```

Which might be handy if you have a use for the "Virtual" prefix deleter function in other places.

The other approach that suggests itself is to standardise your input via an enum (essentially parsing it), like:

```
enum Thing {
    case ride
    case run

    init?(_ s: String) {
        switch s {
        case "Ride", "VirtualRide":
            self = .ride
        case "Run", "VirtualRun":
            self = .run
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var str: String {
        switch self {
        case .ride: return "Ride"
        case .run: return "Run"
        }
    }
}

let example = OrderedSet(["Ride", "VirtualRide", "Run", "VirtualRun"].compactMap(Thing.init(_:)).map(\.str)))
```